# Ordered and unordered map

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand ordered and unordered map

I understand that ordered map will sort your list and unordered map will not sort it. base from this [site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

But why is this code get sorted anyway

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;

map.insert(std::make_pair("hello", 1));
map.insert(std::make_pair("world", 2));
map.insert(std::make_pair("call", 3));
map.insert(std::make_pair("ZZ", 4));

for(auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end();it++)
{
    std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
}
```

result:

```
world
hello
call
ZZ
```

I dont get it. its supposed to be hello then world then call then ZZ. How did the world came first if its unordered container is not suppose to sort it.

Comment: *unordered*  means there is no order, not that it will keep the insertion order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::hash<std::string>` produces hashes for your input keys. Then, a transformation is applied to these hashes to get a valid index to a bucket in your map (The most basic one one can think of is a simple modulo). These operations take constant time and give you the location of your items. In order to get the good item from a transformed hash, you need it to be at the right place. That is why you observe an apparently random ordering of your inputs.

Now there is ***NO** assumption* you can make on the order of the computed indices. Suppose you would add some more strings in your map. Maybe a rehash would be needed for some strings and your input strings could appear in yet another order.

This has nothing to do with the order of insertion which has no reason to be kept, the purpose of the data structure is to place the items at the appropriate location so that their retreival can be made in amortized constant time (here by placing them at the indices given by the transformed hashes).

Comment: I see. It makes sense now. That means that unordered map is much faster. compared to the normal map

Comment: @HoorahHoorah exactly! Keep in mind it is designed to be efficient only at that one job: given a particular key, retrieve the element labeled by that key.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, the best answer to this question is to say: "study a little about data structures.

Unordered map is supposed to store the data into a special data structure specially designed to be efficient but without any restrictions on storage order, and is therefore "unorderer".

Note that if you get the order of insertion is a type of restriction about the order.

Check out this data structure: hash table.

Answer (score -1):

What they mean by "unordered", is that the elements are returned in a random order (based on element hash).